# i can not push data to big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting *insertAll: (503) Error encountered during execution* from big query.

i have created table using **BigQuery Browser Tool**. i gave empty csv file. i am using service account's p12 file to authenticate. I can get the access tokens. but no mater what i do i can not push any new data. here is my code

```
$g_service_private_key = File::get(storage_path().'/aa-aa.p12');
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.insertdata');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $bq_client_email,
    $scopes,
    $g_service_private_key
);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$client->getAccessToken();
$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

$arr = array(
    'title' => 'why not working',
    'status' => 'working',
);
$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
$payload = json_decode(json_encode($arr));

$rows = array();
$row = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows();
$row->setJson($payload);
$row->setInsertId(time());
$rows[0] = $row;
print_r($rows);
//Stream the event into BQ
$request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest();
$request->setKind('bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest');
$request->setRows($rows);
try {
    $response = $service->tabledata->insertAll($bq_project_id, 'aaa', $bq_table, $request); //fire the insert reques
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Code is good, I think it's also from my previous examples. Maybe the SSL handshake has some problems, check your box's time if it's in sync. Also try a simple query to select something.

Comment: @Pentium10 i am trying from my mac. i tried from server. i get results of queries but i can not add data. very frastating. do i need to do any thing for service account?

Comment: check if the service account email is valid in the google console

Comment: If you provide me your project/target table, I can see if our logs give more illuminating errors.

Comment: @SeanChen do you need project id? is there any security risk if i share these publicly? is there any other way i can send these over you?

Comment: Posting project ids doesn't shouldn't be terribly bad. However, you can also email me at my full name (first and last) @google.com.

Comment: @ZakirHyder Not sure if you got notified of my last comment.

Comment: @SeanChen i sent an email to your email account :D